# Laravel 5.3 API Pagination

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.3, laravel-pagination

i'm working on an API, and i'm stuck at pagination
first i should send only first 10 records later based on the limit value passed by user i should send the `next` 10 records

so for i did this

```
//search Drivers
public function getSearchList($limit) 
{
    //dd($limit);
    $drivers = Driver::paginate($limit)
               ->select('id','first_name','last_name','phone_number','registration_id')
               ->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')
               ->get();

    return Response::json([
        'data' => $drivers->all()
    ]);
}
```

but i'm getting error on requesting `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/search-list/10`

```
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method select does not exist.
```

i thing i'm not doing it right

looking forward for much needed help

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `paginate()` method instead of `get()`:

```
$drivers = Driver::select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'registration_id')
           ->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')
           ->paginate($limit);
```

Comment: thank you so much you guys are awesome as always, can you please tell me the how to show message `not found` if they enter something like 555 if the data is only 120, thank you

Comment: @MrRobot just add something like `if (count($drivers) == 0) { // There is no data }`

Comment: and i want to send the next 10 not the last sent 10 values

Answer (score 1):

```
$drivers = Driver::
          select('id','first_name','last_name','phone_number','registration_id')
           ->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')
           ->paginate($limit);
```

Delete `;` after `paginate($limit)`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination

Comment: thank you so much for your time really appreciate it